# How to move the Stripe gateway from local to production

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, api-gateway

I'm starting creating web applications in React.
Following a tutorial, I have created a Stripe gateway for an eCommerce that it is working in local (the gateway).

Now the Front is in Netlify and the backend (sql database) is in Heroku and it is properly working but I have still the payment process in localhost:3001, so it gives me an error.

What I need to change in the code in order to be ready for production?

```
const express = require('express');
const Stripe = require('stripe');
const cors = require('cors');

const stripe = new Stripe('stripe-public-key...')

const app = express();

const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:8000', 
    credentials:true,
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json())

app.post("/api/checkout", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { id, amount } = req.body;

    try {
        const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount,
            currency: "EUR",
            description: "Products in Cart",
            confirm: true,
            payment_method: id,
            automatic_payment_methods: {
                enabled: true,
                allow_redirects: 'never',
            },
        })
        console.log(payment)
        return res.status(200).json({message : "Payment Successful"})

    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({message: error.raw.message})
    }
})

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Server listening port', 3001)
});
```

EDIT: This is the payment-form.js React Component where the axios POST REQUEST is created and contacting to localhost 3001 to received the data.

So, where to move this to be ready for production?
It is a Capstone Project, so I don't need real payments but I need that the Front that is already connected to the Back (in Netlify and Heroku respectively) can also connect with Stripe to check the payment (with test cards).

```
  const handleSubmitPayment = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
    });
    setLoading(true);
    if (!error) {
      console.log("paymentMethod", paymentMethod);
      const { id } = paymentMethod;
      try{
        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/checkout", {
          id,
          amount: ((props.myCart.reduce((amount, item) => parseFloat(item.price) + parseFloat(amount), 0)).toFixed(2) * 100)
        }, { withCredentials: true });
        props.updateMessage(data.message);
        elements.getElement(CardElement).clear();
        props.handleNext();
      }
      catch(err){console.log("error from axios", error)}
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Comment: You might want to check on their [Go-live checklist](https://stripe.com/docs/development/checklist) - like production webhooks.

Comment: You would want to start investigate from the error, not the code. What exact error does it give you?

Comment: thanks @orakaro. The error that I received is quite evident :
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
http://localhost:3001/api/checkout

I forget to add (and I'll edit the Question right now), that I'm making a POST request to localhost:30001 in a React Component called called Payment Form in order to check if the payment is accepted by Stripe:

  const handleSubmitPayment = async (e) => {
(...)
try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/checkout", {
          id,
          amount: amount
   (...)
} catch (err)...
}

Comment: It looks like a routing error with Node + Express rather than a Stripe issue. You would want to make a simple endpoint works first (ie. a helloworld GET request, then a POST request) before thinking of Stripe API.